# How to use switchmap on service request?

Tags: angular, rxjs

I have a form, with a button that will send an email using the contents of the form. I want to use switchmap because I want to prevent the user from spam clicking and creating tons of HTTP requests, but I don't know how to do this.

Before using switchmap:

```
this.customService.sendEmail(this.emailContents).subscribe(
    data => { console.log("Success") }
)
```

Trying to use switchmap:

```
this.customService.sendEmail(this.emailContents).pipe(
    switchMap(() => this.customService.sendEmail(this.emailContents))
)
.subscribe(
    data => { console.log("Success") }
)
```

But now it sends 12 emails when clicking the button 3 times instead of sending 1 email. I think I am using it in the wrong place, but I'm not really seeing how I'm supposed to use it...

Comment: I don't see what switchMap has anything to do with your goal. If you don't want the user to click multiple times on the button, you should disable the button once it's been clicked.

Comment: Hmm.. maybe I understand switchmap wrong then.. I can certainly disable the button, I was just trying to learn some new things

Comment: Debouncing your clicks can also help.

Comment: ***exhaustMap()*** is the rxjs operator you are looking for. This will prevent further button clicks from firing new observables.

Comment: @godhar I also tried exhaustMap, but it sends many emails like switchmap did.

Comment: Whatever operator you might use won't change anything since every time you click the button, you call the service again, creating a new observable.

Comment: @JBNizet not if you use ***exhaustMap()*** I would try again, it is exactly what this operator is designed to do, I have used it before to handle button event observables.

Comment: @masu9 try returning the HTTP call from inside your operator.

Comment: I agree that you should disable the button. Not only does that provide the behavior you are looking for, but it also provides user feedback. The `exhaustMap` will not solve this problem for you. The `exhaustMap` only ignores subsequent events while the inner Observable has not completed. Once the HTTP request is complete however, the `exhaustMap` will process subsequent events.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your code:

```
this.customService.sendEmail(this.emailContents).pipe(
    switchMap(() => this.customService.sendEmail(this.emailContents))
)
.subscribe(
    data => { console.log("Success") }
)
```

You are calling `sendEmail` multiple times ... both as an outer Observable and within the switchMap.

To use switchMap, you need to have a source stream ... maybe an action stream tied to your button click events. Then you call `sendEmail` within the switchMap as you've shown.

You can think of it this way ... the switchMap needs to be on the action that you want to react to ... which would be the click. And inside the switchMap is where you want to perform the operation you want to limit.

(Though as others have said, switchMap may not be your best choice in this situation since it could still process multiple button clicks, depending on how fast the operation is and how long the user continues to click.)

For example:

```
  clickSubject = new Subject<number>();
  clickAction$ = this.clickSubject.asObservable();

  performAction$ = this.clickAction$.pipe(
    switchMap(item => this.doSomething())
  );

  onClick() {
    this.clickSubject.next();
  }

  doSomething() {
    return interval(500);
  }
```

A better option may be `debounceTime`:

```
  performAction$ = this.clickAction$.pipe(
    debounceTime(250),
    switchMap(item => this.doSomething())
  );
```

See a more complete example here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-subject-order-deborahk

Comment: Exactly the answer I was looking for! I guess I need to look into Subjects too. Thank you.